# missing discriminator field: <>

Tags: java, json, swagger, retrofit2, discriminator

I'm using code generated by swagger. When my client makes request, he fails to read the response with message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing discriminator field: <>
    at com.allot.client.nrf.management.invoker.JSON.getDiscriminatorValue(JSON.java:81)
    at com.allot.client.nrf.management.invoker.JSON.access$000(JSON.java:43)
    at com.allot.client.nrf.management.invoker.JSON$2.getClassForElement(JSON.java:60)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.TypeSelectorTypeAdapterFactory$TypeSelectorTypeAdapter.read(TypeSelectorTypeAdapterFactory.java:65)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.NullableTypeAdapter.read(NullableTypeAdapter.java:36)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.HooksTypeAdapter.deserialize(HooksTypeAdapter.java:86)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.HooksTypeAdapter.read(HooksTypeAdapter.java:54)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
```

I'm using Retrofit2, so I make request in this way:

```
Call<NFProfile> call - getCall();
Response<NFProfile> response = call.execute();
```

And `call.execute()` fails.

What could be a reason? I've read that this issue could be because of `anyOf` / `allOf` in schemas in YAML files. But I don't have it in `NFProfile` schemas. I generated my client from TS29510_Nnrf_NFManagement.yaml file.

Any suggestions? Somebody faced with such problem?

Comment: Can you post the OpenAPI schema definition for the response in question?

Comment: @Helen, Thanks for response. I founded the issue. The issue was in another Object that is responsible for reading responses. And this object had allOf, anyOf, oneOf in it's schema. Swagger generator has a bug and can't always generate code properly if schema contains allOf, anyOf or oneOf. I modified schema, removed allOf, anyOf and oneOf. For now it works.